# change elasticsearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I am trying to change the mapping using following code:

```
PUT /in_test/_mapping/keyword
{
 "properties" : {
            "term" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "index" : "not_analyzed" 
            }
        }
}
```

But it is giving an error:

```
{
  "error": {
"root_cause": [
  {
    "type": "remote_transport_exception",
    "reason": "[tiebreaker-0000000000][172.17.0.24:19555][indices:admin/mapping/put]"
  }
],
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason": "Could not convert [term.index] to boolean",
"caused_by": {
  "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason": "Failed to parse value [not_analyzed] as only [true] or [false] are allowed."
}
},
"status": 400
}
```

I also tried to recreate the index 
by:

```
PUT /in_test
 {
"mappings" : {
    "keyword" : {
        "properties" : {
            "term" : {
                "type" : "text",
                "index" : "not_analyzed" 
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

but I got:

```
{
 "error": {
"root_cause": [
  {
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [keyword]: Could not convert [term.index] to boolean"
  }
],
"type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason": "Failed to parse mapping [keyword]: Could not convert [term.index] to boolean",
"caused_by": {
  "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
  "reason": "Could not convert [term.index] to boolean",
  "caused_by": {
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse value [not_analyzed] as only [true] or [false] are allowed."
  }
}
 },
 "status": 400
 }
```

I also tried to change the _type to keywords but it is still not working.
Basically, I want to search for exact match of string and for that I am referring to this:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html#_term_query_with_text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That documentation page is from Elasticsearch version 2.X (See at the top of the page), and is no longer correct for modern versions of Elasticsearch.

The error you're getting is because "index" now only accepts `true` or `false`, and refers to whether or not the property is indexed at all - Since you're searching by this property, you want it to be `true` (the default).

Instead, try setting the type to "keyword" and it won't be tokenized. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html#_definition_5

```
PUT /in_test
{
"mappings" : {
    "keyword" : {
        "properties" : {
            "term" : {
                "type" : "keyword"
            }
        }
     }
}
}
```

Comment: Actually, that whole guide you're reading is from Elasticsearch 2.X.
I'd recommend using the Elasticsearch Reference guides here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
These are basically a standalone guide as well :)